# Update joined table fields when a MySQL database is updated

Tags: qgis, mysql

Using Qgis I joined feature tables with tables from a MySQL database. I imported the database's tables as new vector layers. Is there any way to update the joined table's fields each time the MySQL database is updated?

Answer (score 2):

Un-checking the 'Cache join layer in virtual memory' would update the join as layers are changed. (But that would do a join everytime any query is performed on the joined layer)